# Why is KDE output negative?

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel-smoothing

As far as I know, PDFs always have positive co-domains, but here is an example of one that outputs negative numbers:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html

```
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.2).fit(X)
kde.score_samples(X)
array([-0.41075698, -0.41075698, -0.41076071, -0.41075698, -0.41075698,
       -0.41076071])
```

Any idea what's going on? And what's the solution?

Here is me trying to do the same but with [my own data](https://bpaste.net/show/76dcbb5bd578):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results are negative because `score_samples()` returns the log density.

From the help message:

```
Returns
-------
density : ndarray, shape (n_samples,)
    The array of log(density) evaluations
```

Comment: Is this common practice? Currently I am doing this: *f = [pow(i, math.e) for i in kde.score_samples(X)]* -- is there any better solution? And thanks :

Comment: No, `pow(i, math.e)` raises $i$ to the power of $e$. You want the reverse. But, it's better to use the exponential function than to manually raise $e$ to the power of $i$. Instead of using a list comprehension, just use NumPy. This will let you operate on entire vectors (and give much better performance). `f = numpy.exp(kde.score_examples(X))` returns the entire vector of results.